# Julia: Strange characters in my string

Tags: utf-8, character, julia

I scraped some text from the internet, which I put in an UTF8String. I can use this string normally, but when I select some specific characters (strange character with accents, like in my case ú), which are not part of the UTF8 standard, I get an error, saying that I used invalid indexes. This only happens when the string contains strange characters; my code works with normal string that do not contain strange characters.

Any way to solve this?

EDIT:

I have a variable word of type SubString{UTF8String}
When I use do method(word), no problems occur. When I do method(word[2:end])  (assuming length of at least 2), I get an error in case the second character is strange (not in UTF8).

Comment: We can help with if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia does indexing on byte positions instead of character position. It is way more efficient for a variable length encoding like UTF-8, but it makes some operations use some more boilerplate.

The problem is that some codepoints is encoded as multiple bytes and when you slice the string from 2:end you would have got half of the first character (witch is invalid and you get an error).

The solution is to get the second valid index instead of 2 in the slice. I think that is something like `str[nextind(str, 1):end]`

PS.  Sorry for a less than clear answer on my phone.

**EDIT:**
I tried this, and it seems like SubString{UTF8String} and UTF8String has different behaviour on slicing. I've reported it as [bug #7811](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7811) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks! Both these methods worked for me: word[chr2ind(word,2):end] and word[nextind(word, 1):end]